# Why is my 'if' statement not creating the alert?

Tags: javascript, if-statement, while-loop, alert, prompt

let input = prompt('What would you like to do: (New, List, Delete, Quit)');

```
while (input === "New") {
    const newToDo = prompt("What would you like to 'ADD' to the list?");
} if (newToDo !== undefined) {
    alert(`${newToDo} added to the list`);
}
```

Comment: because "newToDo" is not in the scope of the if statment. Read about Global and local variables.

Comment: I will read up on global and local variables.  Thank you.

Comment: Actually, the 'if' statement was not located within the scope of the 'WHILE' loop.  Taking away the curly brackets of the 'if' statement, to allow the 'WHILE' loop access allowed the loop to run and the alert to be signaled.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not going to explicitly write the code here as that would be a lost opportunity for learning. However, here are some starting points that would benefit you:

1. You shouldn't be using `const` for a variable whose value is expected to change.
2. As mentioned in the comment, your variable is out of scope meaning it's unrecognizable outside the `while` loop. In order to resolve that, declare the variable prior to the loop.

Comment: Additionally, you can look up the difference between `let`, `var`, `const` variable types

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to evaluate my code, and providing me with the information to perhaps learn from.  I will re-evaluate my code.

Comment: For the record, your answer would not have provided a solution.  My 'if' statement needed only to be moved into the curly brackets of the while loop.  Not inside the curly brackets of itself.

Answer (score 0):

Initialize newToDo in top they it will available all over the scope

```
let newToDo;
while (input === "New") {
newToDo = prompt("What would you like to 'ADD' to the list?");
}
if (newToDo !== undefined)
{
alert(`${newToDo} added to the list`);
}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: The solution was to the move my 'if' statement behind the curly brackets of the while loop.  I had the 'if' statement closed off on itself.